# bind: Cannot assign requested address in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run `ssh -NfL 5432:localhost:5432 root@<ip>` in docker but I'm getting `bind: Cannot assign requested address`.

How can I solve this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:
 -4: force ipv4
 -v: verbose

```
ssh -4 -v -NfL 5432:localhost:5432 root@<ip>
```

Comment: You made me the day!